# Where is the update to 14.04.1 in update-manager?

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, updates, lts

I am not looking for a workaround or a hack.  I am just confused.  14.04.1 has been released now for a week, and one of my machines which is on 12.04, and another one which is on 14.04 both don't have the upgrade options.  I see there is a 14.04.5 release on august 7th but I am not sure what a candence event is.  https://wiki.ubuntu.com/TrustyTahr/ReleaseSchedule

It is hard to believe that it is not an issue that is going to be resolved otherwise I would hope this would be posted on the Ubuntu blog.  I cant be the only one on the last LTS waiting for it to update so I can finally go to the latest kernel and properly use my core i7 graphics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upgrading to a point release is not like upgrading to a new full release.

Just do:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade (dist-upgrade as needed)
```

and you will have the point release installed.

You can confirm your version with:

```
cat /etc/lsb-release

DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS"
```

Comment: I was able to confirm my version on the 14.04 machine to be 14.04.1 using that command.  I had thought that the version would of shown up in Settings->Details.  According to all the documentation though the update to go from 12.04 to 14.04 should show up in the update manager.  Running that command in the past allowed me to go straight from 12.04 to 14.04 without having to wait for 14.04.1 on some of my machines a few months back.

Comment: I'm glad everything worked out. System Settings > Details shows only the major version number, which I agree is a little confusing. Point releases just happen during normal updates from the update manager or the command line. They don't show up in the SC.

Comment: @user310823 For the machine on 12.04, I just read (I don't have the cite handy but there's a question on it) that 12.04 -> 14.04 is delayed because of issues with the HWE.

Comment: Currently, the Ubuntu desktop "about this computer" window will say 14.04, even if 14.0.4.03 was upgraded to according to /etc/lsb-release: `DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS"`. A bit anomalous.

Comment: @matt There was a similar question on that point that I answered a while back. The gist was (as I remember) that the about window uses a pre-made graphic that is not updated for the point releases.

Comment: alternative, you can use `lsb_release -a` command to verify your exact version of ubuntu